# After adding the pagination to material table then the data is not loaded in angular

Tags: angular

This is my ts file where I add pagination after adding pagination data is not loaded.If not add pagination data is showing.

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  title = 'tableData';

  userData  = [];
  
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'userId', 'title','body'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.userData);;

  public errorMsg;

  constructor(private apiService : ApiServiceService ){
    this.apiService.getData().subscribe(customerData => this.userData = customerData,
                                            error => this.errorMsg = error);
  }  

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
**strong text**
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}
`
```

Comment: Please write some example code for your question.

Comment: export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
 

  userData  = [];
  
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'userId', 'title','body'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.userData);;

  public errorMsg;

  constructor(private apiService : ApiServiceService ){
    this.apiService.getData().subscribe(customerData => this.userData = customerData,
                                            error => this.errorMsg = error);
  }  

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}

Comment: Someone please give me the answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

**Try It**

Replace in `app.component.ts`

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { Observable, of as observableOf } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, startWith, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'userId', 'title', 'body'];
  apiService: ApiServiceService | null;
  dataSource: Observable<User[]>;

  resultsLength = 0; // set for total records
  isLoadingResults = true; // loading initialize
  isError = false; // for error

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.apiService = new ApiServiceService(this._httpClient);

    this.dataSource = this.paginator.page
      .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = true;
          return this.apiService!.getData(this.paginator.pageIndex);
        }),
        map(data => {
          // Flip flag to show that loading has finished.
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.isError = false;
          this.resultsLength = data.total_count;
          return data.items;
        }),
        catchError(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          // Catch if the API has return any exception.
          this.isError = true;
          return observableOf([]);
        })
      );
  }

}

// api response interface here
export interface ApiResponse {
  items: User[];
  total_count: number;
}

// user interface here
export interface User {
  created_at: string;
  number: string;
  state: string;
  title: string;
}

/* An example database that the data source uses to retrieve data for the table. */
// you can replace http request with yours

export class ApiServiceService {
  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getData(page: number): Observable<ApiResponse> {
    const href = 'https://api.github.com/search/issues';
    const requestUrl =
        `${href}?q=repo:angular/components&page=${page + 1}`;

    return this._httpClient.get<ApiResponse>(requestUrl);
  }
}
```

Replace in `app.component.html`

```
<div>
    <div
         *ngIf="isLoadingResults || isError">
      <span *ngIf="isLoadingResults">Loading...</span>
      <div *ngIf="isError">
        Request Error
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div>
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
        <!-- ID Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Id</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.number}}</td>
        </ng-container>
  
        <!-- USER ID Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="userId">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>User Id</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.user.id}}</td>
        </ng-container>
  
        <!-- Title Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.title}}</td>
        </ng-container>
  
        <!-- Body Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="body">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef disableClear>
            Body
          </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="white-space: pre-line;">{{row.body}}</td>
        </ng-container>
  
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  
    <mat-paginator [length]="resultsLength" [pageSize]="30"></mat-paginator>
  </div>
```

Replace in `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And your `src/index.html` should be like

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>FirstProject</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```